# Launch Dialog box on page load

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, modal-dialog, script

I have found a script that will run on click but I need it to run on page load.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 //******** Basic Dialog Starts Here ***********/
 function openBasicDialog(tUrl, tTitle) {
     var options = {
         url: tUrl,
         title: tTitle
     };
     SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
 }
 //******** Basic Dialog Ends Here ***********/
```

With the Link code:

```
​</span><a onclick="openBasicDialog(&#39;/Emp1st/SitePages/Suggestion.aspx&#39;,&#39;Employee Suggestion Outline&#39;);" href="#"><span style="font-size: 14px;">Click Here.</span></a>
```

I have tried adding in

```
$(document).ready(function(){// code});
```

and

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   // your code here
}, false);
```

but I have had no success. Any suggestions.

---

I tried this as you suggested.

```
<script>
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){
    var options = {
        url: /SitePages/testing.aspx,
        title: Test
    };
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}, "sp.js");
</script>
```

Still no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try that:

```
<script>
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){
        var options = {
            url: tUrl,
            title: tTitle
        };
        SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
    }, "sp.js");
</script>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion as seen above.

Comment: I assume you added quotation marks around the strings? What's the console saying, are there any error messages? How do you embed the code (Script Editor Webpart, Content Editor Webpart, Scriptblock, ..)? Is Minimal Download Strategy active?

Comment: In trying this did you use the <script type='text/javascript'> ? Appears to be missing

Comment: I basically never use the type attribute. I have never seen a scripting failing because of a missing type attribute. But it doesn't hurt to add it.

Comment: Not sure why it didn't work the the other day when I tried but it worked today. I must have had a typo. Thanks for the help.